# How to get unique value Counts in Excel VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

***Hi All,**

I need to find count of unique values from multiple fields using VBA SQl method, below i have provided all the information.

**My data is look like a***

```
VC      SMP#    JDEStyle    PO#         QTY
ARU     10176   AM7619      F117849OG   64
ARU     10176   AM7619      F118215OG   192
ARU     10176   AM7619      F248062OD   336
ARU     653     AE7968      F114004O6   1
ARU     653     AE7968      F241623O4   18
ARU     653     AE7968      F8340O4     1
GOK     2061    SM8360      F248018OD   246
GOK     2061    SM8360      F248019OD   360
GOK     2061    SM8360      F248020OD   774
GOK     2061    SM8360      F248021OD   66
GOK     2061    SM8360      F248022OD   372
GOK     2061    SM8360      F256233OD   120
GOK     2061    SM8360      F256234OD   360
GOK     2061    SM8360      F256235OD   120
GOK     2061    SM8360      F256236OD   360
IND     10176   AB7049      F118324OG   217
IND     10176   AB7049      F258738OD   87
IND     10176   AB7049      F258739OD   540
IND     2068    AB7011      F114006O6   5
IND     2068    AB7011      F241625O4   3
SEP     10313   AL4596      F117270OG   4005
SEP     10313   AL4596      F118173OG   7911
SEP     10313   AL4596      F254362OD   540
SEP     10313   AL4596      F254365OD   150
```

**and my expecting output is**

```
VC   SMP #  JDEStyle    PO #    QTY
ARU  10176  1            3      592
ARU  653    1            3      20
GOK  2061   1            9      2778
IND  10176  1            3      844
IND  2068   1            2      8
SEP  10313  1            4      12606
```

**But i am getting output like**

```
 VC   SMP #     JDE Style   Count of PO #   Sum of QTY
ARU   10176     3           3               592
ARU   653       3           3               20
GOK   2061      9           9               2778
IND   10176     3           3               844
IND   2068      2           2               8
SEP   10313     4           4               12606
```

**and my code is**

```
Sub Quality_audit()
Dim query1 As String
Dim path As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet
path = "U:\BA\Testing\QA\2014.09.29 SP 15 PROD FLW UP RAW DATA.xlsx"
query1 = "Select  distinct [VC],  [SMP #], Count([JDEStyle]) as 'JDE', Count ([PO #]) as PO, Sum ([Quantity]) as QTY from [Page 1$] where [SMP #] is not null AND ([VC] <> 'HEA' AND [VC] <> 'JMS' AND [VC] <> 'SJL') group by [VC],  [SMP #]"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
With conn
.Provider = "microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;"
.ConnectionString = "Data source = " & path & ";" & _
"extended properties = excel 12.0;"
.Open
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = conn.Execute(query1)

Workbooks.Add

Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs
n = 1
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
Cells(1, n).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
n = n + 1
Next
rs.Close
conn.Close
end sub
```

Your help will be appreciated

Comment: You don't need VBA for this.  A pivot table will do what you need.

Comment: I think in pivot table we have np options to get unique value counts in excel 2010

Comment: It depends - do you have PowerPivot?

Comment: Rory, i dont have powerPivot.

Comment: How many records are you actually working on and would array formulas using native Excel functions be worth pursuing?

Comment: I use pivot tables for this type of situation very often.  You have to think outside the box a bit, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem that you're having not getting the distinct counts correct?  The problem would be with the SQL then, yes?  I think your DISTINCT is in the wrong place.

```
Select
    vc, 
    smp,
    Count(distinct jdestyle) as 'JDE',
    Count (distinct po) as 'PO', 
    Sum (qty) as 'QTY' 
from stuff 
group by VC, SMP;
```

Comment: Steegness, Count(Distinct) function doesn't support in VBA SQl.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a alternate solution you may wish to explore if your returned records are less than several thousand.

[image]

The formulas are:

G2 - `=IF(LEN(G1),IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$999, MATCH(0, IF(LEN(A$2:A$999), COUNTIFS($G$1:$G1,$A$2:$A$999,$H$1:$H1,$B$2:$B$999), 1),0)),""),"")`
Array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Delete), copy to H2.

I2 - `=IF(LEN($G2),SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$999=$G2)*($B$2:$B$999=$H2)/COUNTIF(C$2:C$999, C$2:C$999&"")),"")`
Standard formula, copy to J2.

K2 - `=IF(LEN(G2),SUMIFS($E$2:$E$999,$A$2:$A$999,$G2,$B$2:$B$999,$H2),"")`
Standard formula. Fill all five formulas down as necessary to catch the records you require.

As you are surely aware, array formulas and `SUMPRODUCT` chew up calculation resources remorselessly. However, if a pivot table was ever considered this may be a viable option.